# dojo/request/xhr post returns 404 not found error

Tags: post, dojo, xmlhttprequest, http-status-code-404

I am using dojo/request.xhr to save some content into a .json file stored in my web application. please see below code snippet. When i ran it, "POST http://.../storage/file1.json?key2=value2 404 (not found)" appeared. The file path is correct. What could be wrong? Please help!

```js
onWriteBtnClicked(){
  xhr('./storage/file1.json', 
  {
   method: "POST",
   query: {
    key1: "AL",
    key2: "TX"
   },
   handleAs: "json"
  }).then(function(data){
   console.log(data);
  });
}
```

Comment: You may want to try using the `data` option for forward the json. `query` is just used for to append it to the url like querystring.

Comment: i changed query to data and the same error message. I suspect the issue was with the url. should the url take only a service instead of a .json file?

Comment: url can be anything you want. If you open the 404 url into a browser tab I am sure you will get the same error. Are you sure the server is not case sensitive ? You may have a difference is the case.